Duplicating data on the Mac clipboard using Qt
I'm writing an application in C++ using Qt. That application will run on both Win and Mac. I need to be able to put MIDI data on the system clipboard. Originally, I only needed the data to be copied on the clipboard under the MIME type "audio/midi". But now, I also need to have the same data also under the "Standard MIDI File" MIME type.  This is what I did (in the clipboard.cpp file):
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
bool GuiClipboard::CopyMIDIDataToSystemClipboard(const QByteArray& midiData)
//-----------------------------------------------------------------
{
    bool success = false;
    QClipboard* clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    if (clipboard) {
        QMimeData* qmd = new QMimeData();
        qmd->setData("Standard MIDI File", midiData);  // I added this line
        qmd->setData("audio/midi", midiData);
        
        clipboard->setMimeData(qmd);
        success = true;
    }
        return success;
}

It works fine on Windows, the same data appears on the clipboard under both MIME types.
For MacOS, it's a bit more complicated as we have to reimplement the QMacPasteboardMime class. This is in the clipboard.h file:
#if MAC

#include <QtMacExtras/qmacpasteboardmime.h>
  struct MIDIMime : public QMacPasteboardMime {
      MIDIMime() : QMacPasteboardMime(MIME_ALL) { }

      QString convertorName(){return QString("MIDIMime");}

      bool canConvert(const QString &mime, QString flav){
          QString debug1 = "> canConvert: mime: " + mime + " flav: " + flav;
          LOG (debug1.toLatin1());
         // return mimeFor(flav) == mime || mimeFor(flav) == "Standard MIDI File";
          return mimeFor(flav) == mime || mime == "Standard MIDI File";

      }

      QString mimeFor(QString flav){
          if (flav == QString("public.midi-audio")){
              LOG("> mimeFor: public.midi-audio -> audio/midi");
              return QString("audio/midi");
          }
          if (flav == QString("Standard MIDI File")){
              LOG("> mimeFor: Standard MIDI File");
              return QString("Standard MIDI File");
          }
          return QString();
      }

      QString flavorFor(const QString &mime){
          if (mime == QString("audio/midi")){
              LOG("> flavorFor: audio/midi -> public.midi-audio");
              return QString("public.midi-audio");
          }
          if (mime == QString("Standard MIDI File")){
              LOG("> flavorFor: Standard MIDI File");
              return QString("Standard MIDI File");
          }
          return QString();
      }

      QVariant convertToMime(const QString &mime, QList<QByteArray> data, QString flav){
          //Q_UNUSED(mime);
          //Q_UNUSED(flav);
          
          QByteArray all;
          int cc = 0;
          foreach (QByteArray i, data) {
              all += i;
              cc++;
          }
          QString debug2 = "> convert2Mime: mime: " + mime + " flav: " + flav + " n: " + QString::number(cc);
          LOG(debug2.toLatin1());
          
          return QVariant(all);
      }

      QList<QByteArray> convertFromMime(const QString &mime, QVariant data, QString flav){
          //Q_UNUSED(mime);
          //Q_UNUSED(data);
          //Q_UNUSED(flav);
          QList<QByteArray> list;
          list.push_back(data.toByteArray());
          int cc = list.count();
          QString debug3 = "> convertFromMime: mime: " + mime + " flav: " + flav + " n: " + QString::number(cc);
          LOG(debug3.toLatin1());
          return list;
      }
      
  };
#endif

What happens now is the MIDI data is copied to the clipboard under the type "public.midi-audio" (this is ok), but the type "Standard MIDI File" is empty (this is not ok, it should contain the same data as "public.midi-audio". This is the log content:
Clipboard.h(55) : > flavorFor: Standard MIDI File

Clipboard.h(51) : > flavorFor: audio/midi -> public.midi-audio

Clipboard.h(31) : > canConvert: mime: Standard MIDI File flav: public.midi-audio

Clipboard.h(39) : > mimeFor: public.midi-audio -> audio/midi

Clipboard.h(85) : > convertFromMime: mime: Standard MIDI File flav: public.midi-audio n: 1

Clipboard.h(31) : > canConvert: mime: Standard MIDI File flav: com.trolltech.anymime.audio--midi

Clipboard.h(85) : > convertFromMime: mime: Standard MIDI File flav: com.trolltech.anymime.audio--midi n: 1

Do you have an idea why the clipboard entry for Standard MIDI File is empty?
Thanks in advance!
Marc

I'm not completely sure I'm understanding your code and issue, but "Standard MIDI File" does not seem a valid mime type definition, since: 1. it should always be a two-part syntax: "abc/xyz"; 2. it should not contain spaces; 3. it's not a common/known mime type.

Thanks @musicamante, yet, when I copy notes from a DAW like Reaper, it puts the MIDI data on the clipboard under the type "Standard MIDI File". So, there should be a way to do it.

Where do you see that format? Do you get it from the mime data formats()? I just recalled that on Windows the clipboard formats are a bit different and Qt provides a QWinMime class for that.

I use an app called Clipboard Viewer. There I can see, when copying data from Reaper, the MIDI data under the type "Standard MIDI File".

No, you need to check the formats Qt reports. Use QApplication::clipboard() and get the formats of its metaData() to see the result. Then, as said, you probably need to convert to/from windows clipboard format: if you're on Qt5, use QWinMime, otherwise use QWindowsMimeConverter.

Oh, that's extremely interesting, I will check that, thanks a lot!

Oh, I'm a little bit confused here. Can I really use QWinMime (I'm on Qt5) in a MacOS application?

Oh, I assumed that you were on Windows as macOS support is normally more transparent since it's more close to *nix systems. See QMacPasteboardMime. In any case, it's all explained in the Drag and Drop reference, so, as usual, ensure that you read all the related documentation.
